# I'm trying to add values into an array through a for each loop

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to add values to an array by going through a for loop, but I can't seem to get it to add any values. It doesn't throw any errors, it just comes up with nothing. Here's what I have:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim results() As Long

ReDim results(1 To 6)

For i = 1 To i = 6
    results(i) = 1
Next i

MsgBox results(1)
```

No matter what, the message box just comes up as zero. Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `For i = 1 To i = 6`-->`For i = 1 To 6`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your for loop is written wrong. You wrote the following

```
For i = 1 To i = 6
```

VBA is interpreting i = 6 as an expression (is i equal to 6?) The expression evaluates to false, which gets converted to an Integer (zero), then it attempts to execute `For i = 1 To 0`, which is a null loop so the entire loop gets skipped.

It should be

```
For i = 1 To 6
```